# multiply values from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

number 1

| word | weight |
| --- | --- |
| book | 0.2 |
| water | 0.5 |

number two

| description | book | water |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 1 | 0 |
| abc | 0 | 1 |

I would like to simply multiply each word weight with the values in the second dataframe and paste them in the second dataframe - instead of 1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If match columns names in `df2` without `description` with column `df1.word` you can use:

```
df = df2.set_index('description').mul(df1.set_index('word')['weight']).reset_index()
print (df)
  description  book  water
0         xyz   0.2    0.0
1         abc   0.0    0.5
```

Or if need multiple only matched columns use:

```
m = df2.columns.isin(df1['word'])
df2.loc[:, m] = df2.loc[:, m].mul(df1.set_index('word')['weight'])
print (df2)
  description  book  water
0         xyz   0.2    0.0
1         abc   0.0    0.5
```